# Php function userInfo doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo

I have a problem with my php script. I need it to get all the information about the user. I don't really see what the problem is, but if I do `echo $userInfo->username;` it doesn't show anything. I got a connection to the database.

The function userInfo():

```
    function userInfo(){    

    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $_SESSION['username']));

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $username = $row->username;
        $firstname = $row->firstname;
        $lastname = $row->lastname;
        $worktitle = $row->worktitle;
        $email = $row->email;
        $admin = $row->admin;
        $address = $row->address;
        $city = $row->city;
        $zipcode = $row->zipcode;
        $phone = $row->phone;

      return array(
    'username'      => $username,
    'firstname'     => $firstname,
    'lastname'      => $lastname,
    'worktile'      => $worktitle,
    'email'         => $email,
    'admin'         => $admin,
    'address'       => $address,
    'city'          => $city,
    'zipcode'       => $zipcode,
    'phone'         => $phone
    );  

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="warning">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do some debugging - are you sure that your function is being called? Is the query running successfully? Have you checked that `$row` is being populated properly?

Comment: If i just return $row->username; it works fine. My function is: $user = new User; $userinfo = $user->userInfo();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns an associative array, but from your description, you are accessing the return value like an object.

If you want to access the return value like an object, write the function like this:

```
function userInfo() {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $_SESSION['username']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);  // fetch as object
        return $row;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="warning">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
} 

$userInfo = userInfo();
echo $userInfo->username;  // object syntax
```

If you want to access the return value like an array, write the function like this:

```
function userInfo() {    
    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $_SESSION['username']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  // fetch as array
        return $row;    
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="warning">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
} 

$userInfo = userInfo();
echo $userInfo["username"];  // associative array syntax
```